# PostgresSQL: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: search_path

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pgbouncer

When I try to connect to the database on postgres via jdbc, I get the following error:
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: search_path**

This is how I create the connection:

```
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(profile.connection + Option(profile.catalog).getOrElse("")+ "?currentSchema="+Option(profile.schema).getOrElse(""),
  profile.user, profile.password)
```

I use scala and a custom version of postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### pgbauncer

In short, *pgbouncer* at least my version does not work with the `search_path` parameter, [this](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/89) discussion led me to this idea. There are two ways to fix this problem:

1. Change the *pgbouncer* config file by adding

   ```
   IGNORE_STARTUP_PARAMETERS: search_path
   ```
2. Make a connection without using the `currentSchema` parameter in the connection string and create connection like this:

   ```
   val connection = 
     DriverManager.getConnection(
        profile.connection + Option(profile.catalog).getOrElse(""),
        profile.user, profile.password)
   ```

   Then he will choose the scheme according to the rule set, in *search_path*, they usually set something like `"$user", public`, in this case, when connecting, he first tries to choose the same scheme as the user name, and if he does not find such a scheme, he chooses public.